# Director tries to make a horror film starring an old man!

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I think this is a pretty old film. May be a black & white one. A film director tries to makes a horror film in which lead role is played by an old man, who dies later really after shoot is complete due to some health problem. I don't remember much. Anyone knows it?

Comment: more details would be needed.

Comment: @Ankit - That is all I remember. FYI its an English film.

Comment: Tim Burton's delightful [Ed Wood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Wood_%28film%29)?

Comment: @Walt - You know what you're right! Thank you again because you're the one who answered my previous question also (long back).

Comment: @MANI No problem. :) My favorite Burton movie after Beetlejuice. I can put up a full answer, if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tim Burton's [Ed Wood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Wood_%28film%29) from 1994 was a critically acclaimed, black-and-white film about the life of director [Ed Wood Jr.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_Wood) who made [Plan 9 From Outer Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space) - a movie often dubbed "worst film ever made". It stars Johnny Depp as Ed Wood and Martin Landau (who won an Oscar for the role) as an aging drug-addicted Bela Lugosi. Ed supported Bela and has been meaning to cast him in one more movie when Bela died; Ed then used the last footage he shot with him in *Plan 9* and hired his wife's chiropractor to fill in for him (with his face covered) for the rest of the film. Here's the trailer: